# View multiple windows of same program in taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Can windows be configured so that multiple instances of same program are not grouped together in taskbar. An example of multiple instance if IE :

[image]

I'd prefer in certain situations to view the same program but in its own windows on the taskbar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on the taskbar (not the icon) and go to properties.

[image]

There is an option there to not group the icons and it will show a new "tab" for each item in that group.

[image]

Comment: This enables the labels. How to disable grouping and hide the labels as well (Windows 10)?

Comment: Although each window will have it's own icon on taskbar, they will still be grouped together based on app eg. if you open a notepad doc, then open paint doc, then another notepad doc, you will see both notepad icons together in taskbar, even though paint was opened 2nd. So if you're looking to quickly go to the window opened last, taskbar becomes irrelevant; it's just a collection of icons. The `alt``tab` trick would do the job though

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the taskbar, then choose "Properties", then in the list for "Taskbar Buttons" select "Never combine".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select *Never combine* **taskbar buttons** in *taskbar properties* to have multiple icons of the same program appear in taskbar representing each window.

Although each window will have it's own icon on taskbar, they will still be grouped together based on app eg. if you open a notepad doc, then open paint doc, then another notepad doc, you will see both notepad icons together in taskbar, even though paint was opened 2nd. So if you're looking to quickly go to the window opened last, taskbar becomes irrelevant; it's just a collection of icons showing how many program windows you got open.

[image: taskbar icons]

The <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> function in this case seems to have taken over the taskbar job. To quickly return to previous program/window, press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> keys together once, and release both.

Alternatively, press them together, then release just the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, and you'll see program/window icons ordered when they were opened, each icon separate for a window, instead of all being grouped together for the same program (in taskbar). The problem with this workaround is the whole window content is shown in preview, instead of just the program icon & window title (cluttering up the whole monitor/screen).

[image: alt tab window]